# Eclipse plugin- How can we do some custom action when the file is changed from outside eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a custom editor. I want to perform some actions when the file currently opened in the editor is changed outside the editor.
I am doing the same action when it is being saved from editor but does not know how to achieve it from outside the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IResourceChangeListener` to listen for resource changes in your editor.

Set up the listener with:

```java
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(listener, IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE);
```

and remove it in the editor `dispose()` with:

```java
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().removeResourceChangeListener(listener);
```

In the listener you can do something like this:

```java
@Override
public void resourceChanged(final IResourceChangeEvent event)
{
  IResourceDelta eventDelta = event.getDelta();

  IResourceDelta trackDelta = eventDelta.findMember(IFile you want to check);
  if (trackDelta != null)
   {
     if ((trackDelta.getKind() & IResourceDelta.CHANGED) != 0 &&
         (trackDelta.getFlags() & IResourceDelta.CONTENT) != 0)
      {
        // TODO file contents have changed - add your processing
      }
   }
}
```

Note: This only works for files changed in the Eclipse workspace.

You can track files outside of the Eclipse workspace using `java.nio.file.WatchService`.